# Create file with variable value in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, command

**How can I create a file in unix or linux based on variable value ?**

Ex:

If I store date in a variable in linux,

```
YESTERDAY=`date --date='1 day ago' '+%d-%m-%Y'`
```

it will store value to YESTERDAY as 27-1-2010.

Here I want to create file as name of 27-1-2010,

How can I create file with variable 'YESTERDAY' ?

i want **appending** operation too. 
How can i do this ?

Comment: Unless you've got a compelling reason (as in, some application already expects this date format), please do it Y-m-d and keep yourself sane. d-m-Y never sorts right, and over time, you'll be very upset.

Comment: @Matt Simmons , Thanks i will change at my real time usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YESTERDAY=`date --date='1 day ago' '+%d-%m-%Y'`

cat >> $YESTERDAY

It too working well with appending operation

Answer (score 2):

```
touch $YESTERDAY
```

or

```
echo "something" > $YESTERDAY
```

to append:

```
echo "something" >> $YESTERDAY
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with `echo "foo" >> $YESTERDAY` or `cat otherfile >> $YESTERDAY`

What are you trying to cat?  Or alternately what are you trying to put into the file called 27-1-2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable `$YESTERDAY` in commands. Like `touch $YESTERDAY`, `mv original_file $YESTERDAY`